# php artisan schedule:work - command is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, schedule, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to run php artisan schedule:work command, getting this kind of error message. How can I solve this problem?
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4LZm.png)

Comment: Which version of the laravel are you using?

Comment: @ShabeerAhammed I'm using ^7.0 version

Comment: That is the issue. the `schedule:work` command works on laravel version >8

Comment: @ShabeerAhammed How can I solve this problem,instead of that command ? I want to excecute command daily

Comment: upgrade to laravel 8?

Comment: @Aless55 which kind of problems it can cause?

Comment: If you are trying to this locally, you could achieve it using `schedule:run` command

Comment: @ShabeerAhammed but it runs only once, I need it excecute daily

Comment: is it artisan command or queue job? are you running it on server? (If yes, then you should create a cron job for this. See the **Starting The Scheduler** section [laravel 7.x Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#scheduling-queued-jobs)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using deprecated functions or finding functions that were made in new releases, you should really listen to what the first commenter said and upgrade to a later version as this command was only introduced in **Laravel 8**.

I believe you need to follow two guides. First, upgrade [from Laravel 7.x to 8](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade), then [from Laravel 8.x to 9](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade). This will also mean that you'll upgrade your **PHP** version, so it's pluses all around.

Total upgrade time should be **45 minutes** with an additional **15 minutes** for fixing the inevitable bugs. And **30 minutes** to upgrade your libraries. Spare **1.5 hours** now rather than waste time trying to find get around for features you could've been using.